# Fujitsu ScanSnap ix1300 not recognized

Tags: drivers, scanner, sane, ricoh

I'm unable to connect a new Fujitsu ScanSnap ix1300 scanner to Ubuntu 22.04.2. The program sane-find-scanner recognizes a "possible USB scanner (vendor=0x4c5 [Fujitsu], product=0x162c [ScanSnap ix1300]," but scanimage -L, xsane, etc. don't recognize the scanner. According to the SANE compatibility page, I should be using the sane-fujitsu driver. The fujitsu.conf file doesn't have this product number, so I've added a line to identify it as a USB scanner. That helps with scanimage -L, but not with xsane. I found a web page for the Fujitsu ScanSnap s1300/s1500, which uses the sane-epjitsu driver, and requires that a proprietary driver (Windows?) be installed in /usr/share/sane/epjitsu/, so I may have to do something similar for the ix1300. Perhaps I need to do something similar (but which driver, where, anything else?). Presumably someone has this working somewhere, but that's about all the information I've been able to find. Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.